# Why does full name not update in model when changing the last name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could you please tell me why the full name does not update in model when changing the last name?

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/cqmwJc5dpoDWvai4xeNX?p=preview

```
var loginCntrl=function($scope){
  $scope.testClick =function(){
    $scope.lastname="kumar";
     console.log($scope.fullname)
      alert($scope.fullname)

  }

$scope.name="naveen";
$scope.lastname="sharam";
$scope.fullname=$scope.name+$scope.lastname;
}
```

It shows "naveensharma" on button click. But on button click I change my last name. It should show "naveenkumar" in the model. Why is it not showing? In other words, I change the last name variable "kumar" and the expected result is "naveenkumar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [computed property](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/02/computer-properties-with-javascript-properties/) for `fullname` otherwise the property isn't subscribed to any changes to the `firstname` or `lastname`

```
$scope.fullname = function() {
    return $scope.firstname + $scope.lastname;
};
```

Comment: could you please use plunker ?

Comment: could you pleasegive plunker so that better understand

Comment: @user944513 How do you save in plunker?

Comment: using save or fork button ..give the link